# Type character and print its code with Assembler

Tags: assembly

I am trying to print the code of character(in latin) that has been typed in console. Here is my code (using *TASM*):

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h
begin:
mov ah,01h
int 21h
or al,30h
mov ah,2
mov dl,al
int 21h
ret
end begin
```

But that doesn't work, see the screenshot below( first character is input and than output)
[image]

Thanks in advance!

My OS: Windows XP 32-bit

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 350 x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple code will output all ASCII's from 0 to 99.

```
mov ah,01h
int 21h
aam
xchg al, ah
add ax, 3030h
mov dx, ax
mov ah,2
int 21h
mov dl, dh
int 21h
```

To output in hex (allows all 256 codes to be shown) use

```
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
aam 16
xchg al, ah
add ax, 3030h
mov dx, ax
cmp dl, "9"
jbe OK1
add dl, 7
OK1:
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
mov dl, dh
cmp dl, "9"
jbe OK2
add dl, 7
OK2:
int 21h
```

If your assembler doesn't know about `aam 16` you can replace it by `db 0D4h,10h`

Comment: can you please edit your answer to print codes in hex not in dec? Thanks in advance